# Neo4j cypher query for updating nodes taking a long time

Tags: performance, neo4j, cypher, database-performance, neo4j-apoc

I have a graph with the following:

(:Customer)-[:MATCHES]->(:Customer)

This is not limited to two customers but the depth does not exceed 5. The following also exists:

(:Customer)-[:MATCHES]->(:AuditCustomer)

There is a label :Master that needs to be added to one customer node in a matching set depending on some criteria.

My query therefore needs to find all sets of matching customers where none have the label master and add that label to one node in the set. There are a large number of customer nodes and doing it all in one go causes the database to become very slow.

I have attempted to do it using apoc.periodic.commit:

```
CALL apoc.periodic.commit("MATCH (c:Customer) 
WHERE NOT c:Master AND NOT (c)-[:MATCHES*0..5]-(:Master) WITH c limit {limit} 
CALL apoc.path.expand(c, 'MATCHES', '+Customer', 0, -1) 
YIELD path UNWIND NODES(path) AS nodes WITH c,nodes 
order by nodes:Searchable desc, nodes.createdTimestamp asc 
with c, head(collect(distinct nodes)) as collectedNodes 
set collectedNodes:Master 
return count(collectedNodes)", {limit:100})
```

However this still causes the database to become very slow even if the limit parameter is set to 1. I read that apoc.periodic.commit is a blocking process so this may be causing a problem. Is there a way to do this that is not so resource intensive and the DB can continue to process other transactions while this is running?

The slowest part of the query is the initial match:

```
MATCH (c:Customer) 
    WHERE NOT c:Master AND NOT (c)-[:MATCHES*0..5]-(:Master) WITH c limit {limit}
```

This takes around 3.5s and the entire query takes about 4s. There is very little difference between limit 1 and limit 20. Maybe if there is a way to rewrite this so it is faster, it might be a better approach?

Also, if it is of any use, the following returns ~70K

```
MATCH (c:Customer) 
WHERE NOT c:Master AND NOT (c)-[:MATCHES*0..5]-(:Master)
RETURN COUNT(c)
```